# SCNTransaction not animating correctly in Scene Kit SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, animation, translation, scenekit

I'm trying to move an object over a period of ten seconds from y coordinate 0 to y coordinate 10. the object is created at y coordinate 0. The problem is when the animation starts, the object pops to the end position for like one second or so then pops back down to the starting position and begins the animation properly. Why is the object moving to the end location instantly, and how can I prevent this from happening?

```
//create box bottom
func createGrabBox() {
grabbottom = grabBox.rootNode.childNodeWithName("grabbottom", recursively: true)!
grabbottom.position.y = 0
grabbottom.geometry!.firstMaterial!.transparency = 0.5
grabbottom.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: nil)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(grabbottom)

//animation snippet
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(10.0)
SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock() { }
grabbottom.position.y = 10
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't manipulate the position of a dynamic body. Use a kinematic body for that.

Comment: switching to kinematic didn't work either.   Now it's just at the ending position without any translation occuring

Comment: scratch that last comment.  It's working.  I forgot I added this code SCNTransaction.setDisableActions(true).  I removed that and it's working.  Thanks!